# Struts 2 single jsp page to execute multiple different methods

Tags: struts2

I am migrating from struts 1 to struts 2 framework. Based on struts 1 framework parameter=method attribute, I am able to execute different methods using the same jsp page by adding a hidden field "method".

How do I achieve the same in struts 2?

My Action class:

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    public String methodA() {
        return "a";
    }

    public String methodB() {
        return "b";
    }
}
```

My JSP page

```
<s:form action="MyAction">
    <s:select label="Method Name"
       name="method"
       headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Method"
       list="#{'01':'A', '02':'B', [...]}"
       value="selectedMethod"
       required="true"
    />
    <s:submit type="button" name="submit" />
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that by changing the "action" url before submitting.

Check out **Wildcard Method** and **Dynamic Method Invocation** [here](https://struts.apache.org/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-WildcardMethod)

Though, the dynamic Method Invocation can be considered a [Security Vulnerability](http://www.brucephillips.name/blog/index.cfm/2011/2/19/struts-2-security-vulnerability--dynamic-method-invocation)

Comment: changing the form.action using JavaScript?

Comment: @youcanlearnanything yes, something like " document.myform.action ='actionName_method.action' ",  you can do that, say, within select's onChange method. (sorry, if you are expecting the exact code for your case - cannot provide you with that - due to lack of time and resources)

Comment: I got it. I couldn't think of any other way too! I just wanted to know if there is any alternative.

Comment: @youcanlearnanything you can also use hidden field as you have before  if you use dynamic method invocation -> <s:hidden name="method:create" value="foo" /> (it is described in the 1st link I have provided in the answer)

Comment: that's a security risk which I will avoid. doing so

Comment: @youcanlearnanything if you are using struts 2.5, then take a look at   [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218790/wildcard-action-mapping-no-longer-working-after-updating-to-struts-2-5) also, to avoid any confusion. There are now more strict rules regarding usage of wildcard method.